# Why is VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE used in vastly different situations?

Tags: virtualbox

I looked at the VBox sources on GitHub, and see that `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE` is a catchall error message that is applied in numerous situations, e.g., in the following methods (among others):

```
resumeWithReason, pauseWithReason, enableVMMStatistics, onlineMergeMedium, enumerateGuestProperties, onUSBDeviceDetach, accessGuestProperty, onUSBDeviceAttach, onSharedFolderChange, onUSBControllerChange, onVRDEServerChange, onStorageDeviceChange, onMediumChange, onStorageControllerChange, onParallelPortChange, onSerialPortChange, onNetworkAdapterChange, uninitialize, updateMachineState, assignRemoteMachine, assignMachine (target: xpidl, midl), getRemoteConsole, removeDeviceFilter, createDeviceFilter, teleport, restoreSnapshot, deleteSnapshotRange, deleteSnapshotAndAllChildren, takeSnapshot, removeSharedFolder, etc.
```

**Is there a reason that the same error is used in vastly different situations?**

This makes it near impossible to know the reason why the guest entered the `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE`.

Wouldn't it be better to have individualised error results, linked to the method that produced them, e.g., `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE_in_removeSharedFolder` or `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE_in_takeSnapshot`?
That way, the user will at least have an inkling why her guest VM entered the `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE`.

**If I want to create a branch of the VBox codebase, where I'd implement individualised error messages, which documentation should I read to know which files in [vbox on github](https://github.com/mirror/vbox) should be changed?**